# iOS Is there a way to sort an NSDictionary's keys by 2 values?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, dictionary

Let's assume I have this NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *d = @{
                    @"124":@[@"-40",@"1489365614.248664"],
                    @"130":@[@"-40",@"1489365604.258358"],
                    @"134":@[@"-40",@"1489365615.49739"],
                    @"53":@[@"-40",@"1489365610.502131"],
                    @"57":@[@"-40",@"1489365609.253352"],
                    @"73":@[@"-40",@"1489365608.004844"],
                    @"89":@[@"-44",@"1489365611.750874"],
                    @"91":@[@"-64",@"1489365606.755874"],
                    @"93":@[@"-45",@"1489365605.507149"],
                    @"96":@[@"-45",@"1489365613.000054"]
                    };
```

I can sort it by the first value of the array like this:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [d keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(NSArray *obj1, NSArray *obj2) {
    return (NSComparisonResult)[obj1[0] compare:obj2[0]];
}];
```

And will return this array:

```
@[73,134,53,124,130,57,89,96,93,91]
```

Which translates to the dictionary been like this:

```
@{
@"73": @[@"-40",@"1489365608.004844"],
@"134":@[@"-40",@"1489365615.49739"],
@"53": @[@"-40",@"1489365610.502131"],
@"124":@[@"-40",@"1489365614.248664"],
@"130":@[@"-40",@"1489365604.258358"],
@"57": @[@"-40",@"1489365609.253352"],
@"89": @[@"-44",@"1489365611.750874"],
@"96": @[@"-45",@"1489365613.000054"],
@"93": @[@"-45",@"1489365605.507149"],
@"91": @[@"-64",@"1489365606.755874"]
};
```

Now, as you might imagine, the second value of the array in the dictionary, is a timestamp. And if the first values are equal, I'd like to sort by this timestamp so I can get the newest one first.

If I was able to do that, I should be getting back an array like this:

```
@[134,124,53,57,73,130,89,96,93,91]
```

Which would translate the dictionary to actually be like this:

```
@{
@"134":@[@"-40",@"1489365615.49739"],
@"124":@[@"-40",@"1489365614.248664"],
@"53": @[@"-40",@"1489365610.502131"],
@"57": @[@"-40",@"1489365609.253352"],
@"73": @[@"-40",@"1489365608.004844"],
@"130":@[@"-40",@"1489365604.258358"],
@"89": @[@"-44",@"1489365611.750874"],
@"96": @[@"-45",@"1489365613.000054"],
@"93": @[@"-45",@"1489365605.507149"],
@"91": @[@"-64",@"1489365606.755874"]
};
```

Hope it makes sense and someone has an answer.
Thanks

Comment: Dictionaries aren't sortable.

Comment: @rmaddy, ill-chosen words in the title.  The OP wants a sorted array of the keys.

Comment: I'll reword the title. Sorry about that

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how to word it. @danh any suggestion?

Comment: I made a suggestion by editing the title

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing your answer in my code now. Will come back to accept your answer if everything goes as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's a tie, just compare the second values...

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [d keysSortedByValueUsingComparator: ^(NSArray *obj1, NSArray *obj2) {
    NSComparisonResult result = [obj1[0] compare:obj2[0]];
    return (result == NSOrderedSame)? [obj2[1] compare:obj1[1]] : result;
}];
```

Comment: Flawless. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use this logic:

```
NSArray *sort = [d keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^(NSArray *obj1, NSArray *obj2) {
    NSComparisonResult result = [obj1[0] compare:obj2[0]];
    if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
         result = [obj2[1] compare:obj1[1]];
    }
    return result;
}];
```

Comment: hey, I had to choose the other answer as it is the same as yours but it was made 6 seconds before yours. I upvoted yours though. Thanks!

Comment: I saw that answer too. But it was wrong when he wrote [obj1[1] compare:obj2[1]] which shows the older time stamp first. Then he edited to make it right. But that's ok.

Comment: I'm up-voting, too, for your recognition that the OP's desired sort was descending.